# What is a better way to read each line in a file in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, file

```
cat  swerror.txt | while read Wrapper 
do
......
done
```

Hi all, I want to read each line in a file and then make a whole url to do some thing. The above scripts worked, but what is a better way to read file line by line? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with *some progress*. Is the script wrong, or do you want it to make it more efficient?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If you want to checkout the entire `svn` repository, you can do this using a *single* command.

Comment: Calling `svn checkout` in each iteration of the loop is going to take a lot longer than inefficiently reading the file line by line. It is unclear what you're asking. Please [edit] to clarify what you want.

Comment: I want to make it more efficient. Any good idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice example of the [*useless use of cat*](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html), simply use IO redirection:

```
while read -r Wrapper 
do
    ...
done < swerror.txt
```

The use of `-r` in `read` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28170253/67579).

It saves you the creation of a pipe and a process (`cat`) and will thus be more efficient. Although as @TomFenech says, `svn` (the inner loop command you first gave) will probably be the dominant factor since it requires network traffic. And anyway, in most cases the runtime will not improve much by optimizing pipes, etc.

Comment: This also allows you to use variables inside the loop and reference them outside of it.